# Next 13: Preload data/user settings from localStorage

Tags: reactjs, next.js, local-storage, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I have a tabular React component in Next.js which uses localStorage to save and restore user's preference of which columns to show and which ones to hide. Naturally, I want the component to load the user's preference before rendering any part of the table.

Using `localStorage` directly in state variable initialization causes `ReferenceError` at the server about `localStorage` being undefined because of SSR.

```js
const [columnVisibility, setColumnVisibility] = useState<VisibilityState>(
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("columnVisibility") || "{}"))
```

Using `useEffect` to load the preferences takes time and renders the table header before loading them fully, hence showing the default configuration instead of the user-defined one for a moment.

```js
const [columnVisibility, setColumnVisibility] = useState<VisibilityState>()
useEffect(() => {
     setColumnVisibility(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("columnVisibility") || "{}"))
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [string, setString] = useState<string>("default")
// define default value

useEffect(()=>{
   localStorage.getItem("stored-string") || "default"
}, [])
```

Is this solution works ?